Can the Dirac trace of two gamma matrices always be made positive?
I'm doing a calculation where I have a number of traces of just two slashed matrices.
When Calculating a Dirac trace of two slashed matrices, we have the identity:
$$Tr[\displaystyle{\not} a \displaystyle{\not} b] = a_\mu b_\nu Tr[\gamma^\mu\
\gamma^\nu] = 4a_\mu b_\nu \eta^{\mu\nu} = 4(a\cdot b). $$
A handful of these traces have a negative sign in them,
$$Tr[- \displaystyle{\not} a \displaystyle{\not} b]. $$
Can I just ANTI-commute the two matrices to eliminate the negative sign,
$$Tr[- \displaystyle{\not} a \displaystyle{\not} b] = Tr[\displaystyle{\not}b  \displaystyle{\not} a],$$
and then use the cycling property to move the a matrix back to the front
$$Tr[\displaystyle{\not}b  \displaystyle{\not} a]  = Tr[\displaystyle{\not}a \displaystyle{\not} b]? $$
Does this mean,
$$Tr[-\displaystyle{\not}a  \displaystyle{\not} b]  = Tr[\displaystyle{\not}a \displaystyle{\not} b]? $$
Have I made a gross mistake in my understanding of commuting gamma matrices? Or is this a fun quirk of the Clifford algebra that happens when you are taking the trace of only two matrices?
Edit:
I misspoke or maybe was too loose with my language when I originally posted this. I am specifically interested in the Dirac gamma matrices which follow the anti-commutation relation,
$$ \gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu + \gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu = 2 \eta^{\mu\nu}.$$
Does this change anything? or is my conclusion still wrong.

The anti-commutation relation says that they don’t anti-commute. If they anti-commuted the right side would be zero.

@Ghoster Thank you! I was getting it twisted with the fact that the gamma-5 matrix does anti-commute.

Quite generally, you have ${\rm Tr}(-A B)=-{\rm Tr}(A B)=-{\rm Tr}(BA)$ for arbitrary square matrices $A$, $B$.

+1. Let me add that $Tr(AB)=Tr(-AB)=-Tr(AB)$ implies $Tr(AB) = 0$, and hence OP's conclusion is incorrect
